# iOS show 360º photos

Tags: ios, photo, 360-degrees

I have a 360º photos (from Samsung Gear 360 2017) and I want to show them in my app. I have tried several option from Github, but they are mostly out-of-date.

Latest try was to use SCNSceneKit.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.jpg", [paths objectAtIndex:0], delegate.strSelPhotoID];


UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

// Set the scene
self.sceneView.scene = [[SCNScene alloc]init];
self.sceneView.showsStatistics = NO;
self.sceneView.allowsCameraControl = YES;

//Create node, containing a sphere, using the panoramic image as a texture
SCNSphere *sphere =   [SCNSphere sphereWithRadius:30.0];
sphere.firstMaterial.doubleSided = YES;
sphere.firstMaterial.diffuse.contents = image;

SCNNode *sphereNode = [SCNNode nodeWithGeometry:sphere];
sphereNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0,0,0);
[self.sceneView.scene.rootNode addChildNode:sphereNode];


// Camera, ...
_cameraNode = [[SCNNode alloc]init];
_cameraNode.camera = [[SCNCamera alloc]init];
_cameraNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, 0);
[self.sceneView.scene.rootNode addChildNode:_cameraNode];
```

this works more and less to show the photo, but:
- panning around the image is not very nice, distortions very high, -when touching with two fingers it goes to a very high zoom level

Is there a 360º Panoramic photo SDK out there or what could be the best option to implement?

Answer (score 0):

With [Google VR SDK](https://developers.google.com/vr/ios/vr-view) you can easily do this. It works with 360 pictures and videos.

There are samples on Github. https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-ios-sdk

Comment: Thanks for this, just tried this before, the problem with GVRSDK is that it needs bitcode enabled = NO. Anyhow, setting to NO, doesn't let build the app.